# How to force all files in git repo to enter the staged state, with no actual changes?

Tags: git, clang-format

I am trying to use `git clang-format` to format *all* the files in a repo[1], not just a given commit or diff. My first thought was just mark every file as staged and then run the command. Then any files that aren't changed would result in a no-op, but all the files that do have formatting changes would be fixed, staged, and then committed

However, I cannot find a reliable way to force all files to enter the 'staged' state. Even force touching all the files didn't trigger their inclusion.

I have tried variations of `git add -a` or `git add -a -f` and that doesn't work.

[1] Yes I could use `clang-format` directly but depending on versions of `clang-format` and `git clang-format` they produce different outputs.

Comment: @matt They are in the index, but have bad formatting. I wanted to clean up the bad formatting over the whole repo. The question is more about how to put everything already in the index into the 'staged' state.

Comment: What's the difference between being in the index and being "in the 'staged' state"?

Comment: i think `git clang-format` only considers files in the `staged` state.

Comment: @matt: `git clang-format` runs `git diff --cached` to find index files that differ from the committed version, then extracts those files and runs them through `clang-format`. It has a bunch of fancifications but the general idea is to avoid clang-format-ing files that don't have any new code in them. I think you can also set it up to carefully adjust only *part* of the updated files (using `git add -p`).

Comment: @torek Ooooo I see, that makes total sense.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that all files are *always* staged.  They're just not *called* `staged` unless the staged copy is *different from* the committed copy.

Given that you plan to run everything through a formatting command, you could simply deform each file (badly format a line at the top, for instance) to fool the software, but it would be better just to use the formatter directly on the working tree files.  To handle the footnote-1 issue, find the right formatting directives to get the right formatting.

Comment: Its more of a bug in clang-format than the directives. Both git clang-format and clang-format refer to the same style file.

Comment: But [`git clang-format` is just a script that runs `clang-format`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/tools/clang-format/git-clang-format). Run the right clang-format, with the right directives, and you're set.

Comment: Ah, i see that `clangFormat.binary` points to another version of `clang-format` that is not in my path. That's probably why there is a discrepancy.

Comment: @Moop: That would do it. Every time we upgraded clang versions, we had to mess with the formatting directives...